# Database trigger does not work with ArcGIS featureservice

Tags: postgresql, arcgis-server, sql, enterprise-geodatabase

I have set a database trigger on a featureclass in a (PostgreSQL) geodatabase that calculates one field. This works fine when editing in ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro, but when I insert a new record through a featureservice, the field remains empty.

The plpgsql code is not much more than this:

```sql
if tg_op='INSERT' and new.fieldname is null then        
    new.fieldname := 'Test';
end if;
return new;
```

I can see that the trigger is being called (*before insert*), and also that the value is actually set in `new.fieldname`. Furthermore, when I add a separate trigger that fires *after insert*, I can see that `new.fieldname` is still set to `Test`.

- I'm using the same database user in both ArcGIS Server and Desktop
- The featureclass has archiving enabled, but AFAIK that shouldn't matter, besides, it works in ArcGIS Desktop
- The featureclass is not versioned
- I don't see any error message in the PostgreSQL logfile

**Update 9 may 2023:**

I've done some more testing, and I found out that when I call the trigger *before update*, it works for ArcGIS Server, but not for ArcGIS Desktop.

I could of course use both events, and that sort-of works, but the value I'm writing is generated by a sequence, and there is a requirement that values are sequential. With both events, the sequence is accessed twice when inserting through ArcGIS Server (even though I'm checking the value for NULL), causing 'missing' values.

Comment: Where are the values missing - the feature service, the feature class, the postgres table, or all three?

Comment: @jbalk the postgres table, so all three.

Comment: Does the post-insert trigger not work with ArcGIS Desktop?  If it does, then why not just use that one?  If both are required (barring figuring out the issue with the pre-insert trigger), you might do a check in the second trigger by querying for the record by ID & check that the result's <fieldname> isn't null before setting it.

Comment: @Zack Both triggers have a non null check, but for some reason, after pre-insert, the value is reset to null, which causes an unwanted increment of the sequence during post-insert

Comment: What I'm recommending in the second trigger is to run a query on the table for the new record, check *the queried record* fieldname value (not new), and if it is also null then use currval() instead of nextval() to get the sequence value without incrementing it.